# java Jframe refuses to render when called from outside

Tags: java, swing, jframe, progress-bar

I have a totally rediculous issue.

Situation:
I have a reporter.java class from which I call a small JFrame class (status.java) with a StatusBar in it. My reporter.java has a main function from which I test the correctness. If I do that everything works totally fine.

And now comes the weird thing.

I have JFrame class (menu.java) with a menu bar from which I create an instance of my reporter class. When I call the reporter class from there instead of from its main function, the progress class opens as requested, but it refuses to render. All I get is an empty frame which I even cannot close as it seems frozen.  The process in the reporter is exactly the same...

I have to add that the tasks in the reporter class creates hundreds of tables into a pdf file. That soaks up the entire cpu capacity of my win10 for several minutes.

Ah, one more info: I created all those classes in NetBeans 11.

Here my Code snippets:

```
public class Progress extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    JProgressBar progressBar = null;

    public Progress (int maxvalue) {
        initComponents();
        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, maxvalue);
        jPanel1.add(progressBar, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 20, 340, 30));
        progressBar.setVisible(true);
        setVisible(true);
        this.repaint();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 100));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 100));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 100));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 400, 100));

        pack();
    }  

    public void updProgress(int wert) {
        progressBar.setValue(wert);
        progressBar.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
        repaint();
    }

    public void kill() {
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();
    }
    }
...
```

Here the calls from my reporter class (spead over my code)

```
Progress bw = null;
bw = new Progress(table.getRowCount());

bw.updProgress(x);

bw.kill();
```

and I call the Reporter class from my menu with a

```
Reporter r = new Reporter();
```

The exact same line can be found in the main function too. 
As said, when I call the reporter class from its main function, it works fine. When I make the entirely same reporter class call from the menu class, the progress bar seems to freeze up. I tried it with a simple JLabel instead of the progress bar. This does not render either. It must be the JFrame that has an issue. Maybe the reporter class is at its limits and freezing up too. It has no GUI and works in the background, so I cannot check that.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens???

Comment: Sounds like you may be obstructing the AWT event dispatch thread with long-running logic.  Is `new Progress` called in the EDT thread (such as from an event listener)?  Are you invoking any long-running calls right after that?

Comment: Hi.No, I do not have an event listener. I call the constructor of my progress class at the beginning of my reporter routine, call the updProgress function in my loop each time a new iteration (table) is done and call the kill command at the end when the loop is done. What I do not understand is that the system acts differently when I initiate the reporter from main and from outside. The reporter does exactly the same things afterwards...

Comment: A long-running loop would also hold up the processing of events in the event dispatch thread.  Consider providing a shortened form of the the Reporter class which we can compile and which demonstrates the problem (that is, a [mre]).

Comment: Thanks VGR. I guess that is difficult. My reporter class has about 600 lines of code and there are countless SQL calls to a database in there. These db calls are what makes them long running. But the reporter class works fine by itself. Ony when I initiate the reporter from inside another swing JFrame the progress bar frame does not render anymore. Maybe as suggested could it be that the two JFrames block each other? I understand that all swing classes run in the same thread. Can I force the two JFrames to run in two threads to avoid the lock? Maybe suggest. I am a java amateur :-)

Comment: All Swing and AWT calls must be made in the event dispatch thread.  However, other things, especially long-running tasks like database calls, should be made in a different thread.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/ for examples of how to accomplish this.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Answer (score 1):

**** I GOT IT !!!! ****

I played around over and over with my code until I finally found the solution...

When checking the menu class from which I called the reporter process, I reallized that while the reporter is running, the menu class is locked and unresponsive. I could not move, resize or close the thing...

So I started professor Google and found out how to wrap my reporter class in its own thread. For that I had to make the reporter implement java.lang.Runnable and then from the menu class called the reporter like this

```
Reporter r = new Reporter();
r.setWhere(" year='" + cyear +"'");
r.setReport("T");
Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
t1.start();
```

I had to create the setWhere and setReport functions to dump the parameters into the class, so I can the make the actual function call that causes the heavy load from within the run() function of the reporter class.

This then decouples the Swing GUI from the heavily iterating reporter class and this way all my frames do show as I want them to show.

This was a new concept for me. Although they showed us the concept of threads in my java class (18 years ago), I never had to use it yet. I never had an application that where classes lock each other or because of the heavy CPU load it takes.

Interestingly enough (for me as an amateur), despite the busy reporter process, I can actually call and update the progressbar frame from inside the reporter class without wrapping it into yet another thread. All it took was to decouple the menu class.
The non-GUI reporter class and the progressbar GUI still seem to work together without blocking each other.